# Why is java.io.RandomAccessFile.writeChars(String s) treating a space character ("\u0020") as 1 byte?

Tags: java, character-encoding

I understand this method is specified by `writeChars` in interface `DataOutput` and the Javadoc states:

> Writes every character in the string s, to the output stream, in order, two bytes per character

What I can't understand, and I've been researching many of the other encoding questions on SO, is that if `writeChars` writes explicitly 2 bytes per character and makes no distinction between any characters (so my take on that is that's it's no longer a question of what encoding the Java runtime uses, but any file system will see a character as 2 bytes) then why is it treating the `SPACE` character as one byte?

I'm probably missing something incredibly simple, and there are dozens of questions here about encoding which are helpful, but I can't seem to apply these to my question.

Edit* I was about to provide my code, but I am getting the expected output now after running a test one one set of inputs (not the entire input file) and based on the marked answer, I was clearly wrong.

Comment: If you are going to down-vote then tell me what's wrong with my question which is more constructive and then in the future SO might not be littered with a subprime (however honest) question.

Comment: Where is the code and the output that supports this assertion?

Comment: Providing now, thanks

Comment: I wrote a sample and I could see 0020 written as 2 bytes as expected. used `file.writeChars("a b");` and hexdump of the file displayed `6100 2000 6200`, ie 6 bytes in total.

Comment: @E.Rowlands As you have now accepted that your problem cannot be reproduced, that's what's wrong with your question, along with the total lack of evidence or test case. The interval between the downvote and my explanation was about two minutes. Don't be so trigger-happy, either with questions or with comments. Your futile question should be deleted.

Comment: OK, that's fair. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I've flagged it to be closed, as I cannot delete it. In hindsight, this was a pretty terrible question. As an undergraduate programmer, I still forget to test problems outside the scope of a large program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the behavior that you describe.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("test", "rw")) {
            raf.writeChars("\u0020");
        }
    }
}
```

This creates a file called "test" in the current directory, which "ls -l" tells me is two bytes long.

Comment: Many thanks. I am getting the expected output now after running a test on one set of inputs (not the entire input file) and confirmed by your answer, I was clearly wrong. I have been stuck on this for nearly a day, so it wasn't a spur of the moment question.

Comment: I am deleting this question - I hope it does not deprive you of your points. *Edit, I am unable too, and for good reason.

Comment: It is going to be deleted anyway.  (FWIW - I voted to ...)

Comment: I flagged it for closure just a sec ago. Anyway, that's enough of your time on this question! Thanks!